# How to change landing page based on search query

Tags: javascript, html, search-engine

I would like to be able to change certain elements on the landing page based on
a)whether it was accessed through a search engine or not
b)what search keywords were used

Is there a way I can change either specific elements on the landing page or the landing page itself based on these criteria?  How?

Thanks so much!

Comment: You would have to process the request on the server, read the `referer` header and parse it to get the incoming search terms. Then you would have to redirect to a different landing page depending on the outcome. I would suggest that you use an A/B testing toolkit for something like this.

Answer (score 0):

On the server-side, detect if the `Referer:` (sic) header contains "google.com" and the querystring "q". If so, then the search terms are in the `q` parameter. Then use whatever server-side engine you're using to modify the page as appropriate.

This has very little to do with Javascript unless you intend to modify the page via client-side scripting.

Answer (score 0):

This questions a bit old but I felt like I should chime in. The current answer is very right in how to get the parameters at a server level, I can see value in getting it via javascript, and even better passing said variables to google analytics for tracking purposes.  As far as changing content you'd want to do this as fast as possible to help keep the user experience ranking high.